Can't open Remix IDE desktop version after upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04
My Remix IDE desktop version, which is a .deb package, is not opening after upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04. It was working fine in 22.04. Whenever I am clicking on the app nothing happens. I have huge collection of notes in that app, so I will lost everything if I uninstall it. Really need some help from Ubuntu team.
